# Removing string out of string rowwise in data.frame using another column in R

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I am trying to cut/remove a string out of a larger string based on another column in a data.frame in a rowwise manner.

For example, in this data.frame `col2` should be removed from `col1`

```
kat1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("A123Testz45", "66Test255"), col2 = c("Testz", "Test2"))
```

with the results being

```
          col1     col2
1     A123 45     Testz
2       66 55     Test2
```

I have tried variations of `sub` with

```
kat1$col1 <- sub(kat1$col2, " ", kat1$col1)
```

but this results in

```
Warning message: In sub(kat1$col2, " ", kat1$col1) : argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Thus, I am thinking of ways to use columns in REGEX to replace these elements in a row-wise manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sub` and `gsub` can't vectorize `pattern` (see `?gsub`). If you are looking for both simplicity and efficiency, try `stringi` (or `stringr` which is a `stringi` wrapper)

```
with(kat1, stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(col1, col2, " "))
# [1] "A123 45" "66 55"
```

Using base R, you could do it (inefficiently) using `apply`, something like

```
apply(kat1, 1, function(x) sub(x[["col2"]], " ", x[["col1"]], fixed = TRUE))
# [1] "A123 45" "66 55"
```

A better base R suggestion by @docendo would be to use `mapply` on vectors in order to avoid matrix conversions

```
transform(kat1, col1 = mapply(sub, col2, " ", col1, fixed = TRUE))
#      col1  col2
# 1 A123 45 Testz
# 2   66 55 Test2
```

Comment: I used to think `stringr` was a wrapper for base functions. Is that not the case?

Comment: @docendodiscimus, No. Just type `str_replace_all` in console and check out the source code. By "wrapper" I mean that it's just the same code under disguise. Compared to `stringi` which is written in C/C++.

Comment: `stringr` used to be a wrapper for base functions until `stringi` came along and strutted its awesomeness about.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, interesting! Another (not so efficient) base alternative would be `transform(kat1, col1 = mapply(sub, col2, " ", col1))`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Nice alternative. Probably better than `apply`